# docker-render vs docker file changing permission

Tags: linux, docker, command, filesystems, host

I am able to change permission of a file when I do `docker-compose exec app <change file permission command>`

However if I try to do from docker file it errors out saying it's only readonly file system.

Changing file inside `/etc` I know they are mounted on runtime wanted to know if its possible to do from dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a script in your `Dockerfile` that you copy into the image and run when the container starts. You are facing this error because images are, indeed, read-only file systems, while containers are mutable. So, adding a script should fix the problem.